# How to pass a Dataframe as train dataframe and another dataframe as Validation to GridSearchCV

Tags: machine-learning, python, cross-validation, gridsearchcv, gradient-boosting-decision-trees

I'm a programmer who tries to find he's way into ML world. so the Question might be basic.

i have data from years 2010-2019. Now i'm trying to test different parameters on gradient boosting regression and i want to use 60% for traning,20% for Validation and 20% for Testing. Due to the nature of the Question that i'm trying to answer. I have already splitted the data into `Train_df` from 2010 till 2014 ,`evaluate_df` 2015 till 2017, `test_df` from 2018-2019.

model should be trained on `trained_df`, and evaluated on `evaluate_df`, finally i use the best model for Test dataframe `test_df`.

This is my code:

```
p_test3 = {'learning_rate':[0.1,0.05,0.01,0.005], 'n_estimators':[500,750,1000,1250,1500]}

tuning = GridSearchCV(estimator =GradientBoostingRegressor( min_samples_split=2, min_samples_leaf=1, subsample=1,max_features='sqrt', random_state=10), 
            param_grid = p_test3, scoring='r2',n_jobs=-1, cv=evaluate_df)
tuning.fit(train_df[['col1' ]],train_df['col2'])
tuning.cv_results_, tuning.best_params_, tuning.best_score_
```

but i got this error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

How can i test the model of GridSearchCV on a dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 dataframes should be combined and then new list has to be generated containing 0 for trainig and 1 for testing. then pass it to cv.

```
combined_df=pd.concat([train_df,evaluate_df])
test_fold = [0] * len(train_df) + [1] * len(evaluate_df)



p_test3 = {'learning_rate':[0.1,0.05,0.01,0.005], 'n_estimators':[500,750,1000,1250,1500]}
ps = PredefinedSplit(test_fold=test_fold)
tuning = GridSearchCV(estimator =GradientBoostingRegressor( min_samples_split=2, min_samples_leaf=1, subsample=1,max_features='sqrt', random_state=10), 
        param_grid = p_test3, scoring='r2',n_jobs=-1, cv=ps)
```